# How to auto-disconnect and connect?

Tags: linux, fedora, connection

I am checking something out in my connection and I just wanted to ask, is there a way to auto-disconnect and connect from the internet.

For example say I want to disconnect now and reconnect to the internet in 0.05 seconds, is there any program that does that on Fedora Linux?

Answer (score 7):

You just have to script the following commands

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: With eth0 being the interface used (it can be wlan0 or anything else).

Comment: You should be able to save a few keystrokes by doing `sudo ifdown eth0` and `sudo ifup eth0`.